# Javascript closure not doing what expected. (Atmoic value not being maintained inside closure)

Tags: javascript, closures, ecmascript-5

I am running into a problem when I am attempting to use a closure to maintain a value that I use upon a callback from an asynchronous function.

The basic order of operations for the functions is:

1. I am attempting to use google to route through several waypoints at once. So route from x->y->z in one call
2. If that fails then the routing is broken up into individual calls and routed through each of them. So x->y and then y->z.

The problem lies in the second part. There is a function that is being called in the single routing that is a synchronous function that leads to another synchronous function that leads to an asynchronous function. Then, when it completes it uses callbacks to bubble itself back up to the original function.

So for example: w would x which would call y which would call z (which is async). Then z would callback to y which would callback to x. When I arrive back in x however I know that the scope of w is gone. However, by using a closure I would expect to be able to retain these values. However, I am still getting the classic problem that closures fix where I only get the final value that a certain value was declared.

This is using ES5 javacript code. Unfortunately my company hasn't gotten to the step where we can use babel to compile on ES6 so an ES5 solution is necessary. I am using jquery and have tried moving the closure to the callback in the way of:

```js
    DatabaseController.getSingleRoute(routingInfo, (function() {
        var testVal = Math.random() 
        return function(result,resultStatus){
            console.log(testVal) // still always the same value
    }())
```

I feel like I am missing something simple here but can't figure out what is happening.

I also feel I should note that I have also changed the code to use multiple instances of the GetSingleRouteHelper class instead of one and set all the values to class variables so setting this.testVal = Math.random() in each instance. Still, upon returning from the callbakcs the value of each class still results in the exact same value.

NOTE: Math.random() is just something I threw in there to try and test my values. It has no bearing on the actual info I am trying to pass (which are latitude and longitude values). So, I can't just move Math.random() inside the callback.

```
    MapsController.getMultipleRoute(requests, function(res, status){
        // this would mean it has failed to get the route via multiple waypoints
        if (!status){
            // break up each request into individual requests
            for(var j = 0; j < results; j++){
                GetSingleRouteHelper.singleCarRoute(singleRouteInfo)
            }

        }
    }

    GetSingleRouteHelper.singleCarRoute = function(routingInfo){
        // what I have switched to to test. I need several atomic values that are generated in this scope. 
        var testVal = Math.random();
        (function(testVal2){
            console.log(testVal2) // here the value is as expected, is each individual random number that corresponds to the outer scopes "testVal" value
            DatabaseController.getSingleRoute(routingInfo, function(result, 
            resultStatus) {
                console.log(testVal2); // is always the final value that was declared. So if above function is run 10 times it will always be the 10th random number here.
            }
        }(testVal))


    DatabaseController.getSingleRoute(data, callback){
         // verifies some values are expected before sending forward
         ...
         GetSingleRoute.get(data, function(a,b){ 
         // verify integrity of return values
         ...
         callback(a,b)
         });
    }


    GetSingleRoute.get= function (data, callback) {
       $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       ws: "fetch_location",
       dataType: "json",
       data: data,
       success: function success(res) {
         callback(result, result.status)
       },
    }
```

I expect that in the callback of the DatabaseController.getSingleRoute function that the value of the testVal to be the correct random number for the scope of the closure. I am getting the final value. So if the function was run twice and the first random num was .3254 and the second random num was .2345 then when the DatabaseController.getSingleRoute callback is activated the console.log statement logs
.2345
.2345
instead of 
.3252
.2345

Comment: `still always the same value` because `var testVal = Math.random()` is only evaluated once

Comment: I don't see the use of closures here since you are passing the `testVal` in the function call, did you add the passing of `testVal` to the closure function to try and simplify the explanation?